# Parsing a string for a particular value

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split

I am trying to parse the string that contains "Enter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast" to check if the user typed "D:" or "R:" and depending on which one, instantiate an object of a particular type, Decaf decafCoffee = new Decaf for "D": and Regular regCoffee = new Regular for "R:". What would be the easiest way to go about this?

```
        Console.Write("Enter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();


        // Loop
        while (!s.ToLower().Equals("q"))
        {
            string[] values = s.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // Trim?
            string name = values[0];
            string demand = (values[1]);
            string cost = (values[2]);
            string min = values[3];

            // Check for > 0 and convert to numbers
            float D = CheckDemand(demand);
            float C = CheckCost(cost);
            float M = CheckMin(min);

            // Create object
            Decaf decafCoffee = new Decaf
```

Comment: with and `if` statement

Comment: How do I find the value of "D:" or "R:" within the last value of the string?

Comment: Does the format ever change? If not try `IndexOf` or `SubString`.

Comment: Or you can be bad and use regex

Comment: Can you confirm what a valid input string might be of the two different types? I'm a bit unclear from your description...

Comment: if (values.Length != 4) continue; // possibly, add an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Decaf decafCoffee = null;
Roast roastCoffee = null;
if (min.StartsWith("D:")) 
    decafCoffee = new Decaf();
else if (min.StartsWith("R:"))
    roastCoffee = new Roast();
else
    // Give an error or something.
```